# T-SQL trigger if only 2 columns are updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying make a trigger that will record the previous data of 2 columns (address and postcode) when a table is updated, including the user and time stamp of the update. I also need the update to only happen if both columns are updated at the same time, if they aren't the change needs to be rolled back. The table I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE PreviousAddress
    (
    a_user char (10)  ,
    a_date date ,
    a_ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    a_CustomerID int ,
    a_PrevAddr char (50),
    a_PrevPostCode char(10),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Previous] PRIMARY KEY(a_id))
```

I can't find any documentation on how to make a trigger that will insert the data into this table but only if the postcode and address are both edited?

My attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Addr_Audit
    ON Customers
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    IF UPDATE(Cus_Addr) OR UPDATE(Cus_Post_Code)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PreviousAddress
    SELECT CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CustomerID, CustomerAddress, CustomerPostcode FROM Deleted 
    END
```

Comment: Change the `OR` to `AND`.

Comment: IF UPDATE(...) should be working (used with AND in your case), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187326.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of use UPDATE, join deleted and inserted tables, this take care of multiple updates, and only inserts those that has changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Addr_Audit
ON Customers
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    -- insert on PreviousAddres those records where
    -- both, Cus_Addr and Cus_Post_Code has changed
    --
    INSERT INTO PreviousAddress
    SELECT     d.CURRENT_USER, 
               d.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
               d.CustomerID, 
               d.CustomerAddress, 
               d.CustomerPostcode 
    FROM       deleted d
    INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON         d.CustomerID = i.CustomerID
    WHERE      i.Cus_Addr <> d.Cus_Addr
    AND        i.Cus_Post_Code <> d.Cus_Post_Code

    -- Rollback changes on the other records.
    --
    UPDATE     Customers
    SET        Cus_Addr = d.Cus_Addr,
               Cus_Post_Code = d.Cus_Post_Code,
               --
               -- add other fields to rollback changes
               --
    FROM       Customers c
    INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON         i.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN deleted d
    ON         d.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    WHERE      i.Cus_Addr = d.Cus_Addr
    OR         i.Cus_Post_Code = d.Cus_Post_Code
```

Just for the sake of the question I'll add another solution. This rollback all changes if detects at least one record where only one of the fields, Cus_Addr or Cus_Post_Code has changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Addr_Audit
ON Customers
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    -- check Cust_Addr and Cust_Post_Code, both has been changed
    -- if not, rollback the whole transaction and raises one error
    --
    IF EXISTS (SELECT     1
               FROM       inserted i
               INNER JOIN deleted d
               ON         i.CustomerID = d.CustomerID
               WHERE      (i.Cus_Addr <> d.Cus_Addr
                          AND 
                          (i.Cus_Post_Code = d.Cus_Post_Code)
               OR         (i.Cus_Addr = d.Cus_Addr
                          AND 
                          (i.Cus_Post_Code <> d.Cus_Post_Code)
               )
     BEGIN
         ROLLBACK TRANS;
         RAISERROR('ERROR: Must change P.C. and address',16,1);
     END


    -- insert on PreviousAddres those records where
    -- both, Cus_Addr and Cus_Post_Code has changed
    --
    INSERT INTO PreviousAddress
    SELECT     d.CURRENT_USER, 
               d.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
               d.CustomerID, 
               d.CustomerAddress, 
               d.CustomerPostcode 
    FROM       deleted d
    INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON         d.CustomerID = i.CustomerID
    WHERE      i.Cus_Addr <> d.Cus_Addr
    AND        i.Cus_Post_Code <> d.Cus_Post_Code
```

Comment: From the question: "I also need the update to only happen if both columns are updated at the same time, _if they aren't the change needs to be rolled back_:" How about the rollback? (I take it to mean if there is a row where only one, but not both, of the columns is changed then roll back the transaction.) Aside: You've assumed that `CustomerId` is unique. Perhaps the OP should clarify the point.

Comment: @pukkaa Did you intend "rolled back" to mean _silently_ undoing changes to only those rows where both `Cus_Addr` and `Cus_Post_Code` weren't changed, or a `rollback` of the entire transaction, perhaps with a `RaIsError` or `throw` to indicate what went wrong?

Comment: @HABO I think this is the best option, a rollback affects the whole transaction. But I can add the two options, this one and another with a rollback.